# printf - Wrong answer on a floating point number

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

I'm trying to divide two numbers together and print the answer but the compiler always gives 1.000000 as the answer, Iv'e tried changing the literals but the answer is still the same somewhat.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
float a = 20 / 12;
printf ("%f", a);
}
```

Any ideas why this happens and how to get the right answer?

Comment: It's because you do *integer* division.

Comment: You need to learn about implicit and explicit type conversions. Only then will you understand as to why this is happening. Try doing 20/12.0 to see the difference

Comment: 20/12 = 1 and 8/12... in C 20/12 is 1, and 20 % 12 = 8

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
float a = 20 / 12;
```

to

```
float a = 20 / 12.f;
```

`20 / 12` is an integer division.

Answer (score 4):

typecast at least one of value as `float` type.

```
float a=(float)20/12;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are performing integer division, if I change

```
float a = 20 / 12;
```

to

```
float a = (float) 20 / 12;
```

I get

```
1.666667
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is integer division, i.e.

```
float a = 20/12 ----- gives you the integer quotient.
```

In order to get a float quotient you can do it like this

```
float a = 20/12.0;    
or
float a = 20.0/12;
```